# Android device can't ping PC while on same network

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, android, ping, adb

I have my Android phone connected to my PC (Windows 10 with Android SDK installed). I set up my PC to have a mobile hotspot so the phone can be connected to the PC network. My PC can ping the phone's IP address, but when I want to ping the PC from the phone's shell (through `adb shell`), it just can't ping it. I have a HTTP server on the PC and need the phone to reach to the server, which is not reachable right now.

The PC IP address is `192.168.137.1`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::345d:2505:82fa:3cd5%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

And the phone's IP address is `192.168.137.159`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:192.168.137.159  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ca7:98ff:feea:cb17/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16441523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8750144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17116348103 TX bytes:4458547550
```

I also tried it without mobile hotspot when both connect to the same router, but same issue again.

**What is the problem?** Does Windows have some settings that need to be changed for visibility and reachability?

Comment: Make sure the PC considers the mobile hotspot as private connection otherwise the firewall will block e.g. PING. Check if the server is running on all network interfaces. Check the Windows firewall on PC side if server port/the server process is whitelisted.

Comment: I couldn't find an option on the PC mobile hotspot to specify the public/private network. Right now it's visible to public. And also the server is a simple HTTP server- no custom port.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1419322/win10-1803-how-to-make-mobile-hotspot-a-private-network

Comment: Did it. It's now private. But still having the issue.

Comment: Interestingly I could not ping android device on local network (host unreachable), Android 9.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Firewall is OFF (or allowed for accepting request from domain/private network).

> For example, from Windows 10 -> Firewall & network protection ->
> Domain Network -> Turn OFF, Microsoft Defender

Comment: May need a reboot as well after